# Does it is a good practice to store some numeric values in wp_postmeta table and fetch it using sql query? (Wordpress, Database)

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

Well i have made a script in which when ever the user watch a complete video the user data (post_id,user_id) will get store in wp_postmeta table. These values are just numeric does it will affect my website performance if the rows in wp_postmeta increases?

```
$chstr =$wpdb->get_results( "select meta_value,meta_key from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = $new_post_id AND meta_value= $cur_user_id" );

if(count($chstr) > 0){ 
    exit;
}else{
    $wpdb->insert( 
        'wp_postmeta', 
        array( 
            'post_id'=> $new_post_id,
            'meta_key' => $new_post_id,
            'meta_value' => $cur_user_id
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s'
        ) 
    );
    die();
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It affects some level.
But fetch post meta with Wordpress  SQL Query it is the best way to get data: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Then what will be the best way to store (post_id,user_id)? and in which table?

Comment: You can store numeric value in post meta with corresponding to meta key. it is not affect anything.

Comment: Basically, i'm storing like this in a new row : meta_key = post_id , meta_value=user_id

Comment: if you have large number of post ids the post meta table has many rows in so I suggest you create an array and save that array in the database table. like 

$postdata = Array(
    'post_id' => $value, 
    );

//Update inserts a new entry if it doesn't exist, updates otherwise
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'postdata', $postdata);

Comment: i have added code in the question can you please check?

Comment: How you get the $new_post_id

Comment: i'm getting it using $_POST method using current page post_id

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to save current user id into database.

```
function save_post_meta_userid( $post_id ) {
   $curr_userid = get_current_user_id();
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_currentuserid', $curr_userid  );
}
```